# Sockpuppets who expose themselves

Tags: discussion, specific-question, user-accounts, sock-puppets

On SO, [Beeph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134751/beeph), asks a question, [What's the simplest way to embed blog functionality on my home page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250496/whats-the-simplest-way-to-embed-blog-functionality-in-my-home-page) which is an exact dupe of [the question asked a few ***minutes*** prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250485/whats-the-simplest-way-to-embed-blog-functionality-in-my-home-page).

When prompted about the earlier question and better just edit that instead of creating a dupe, claims fault on StackOverflow. (How dare they indeed.)

Then, a [Dr Dork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513/dr-dork), appears and [comments on an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250496/whats-the-simplest-way-to-embed-blog-functionality-in-my-home-page/1250520#1250520) saying that they haven't found a host, but just want to engage the reaction and thoughts on the community about options.

Given this, where two accounts speak as one or refer to the other as themselves in a way, is it reasonable to assume that Beeph and Dr Dork are the same person?

Comment: I was going to look, but then Jeff baleted them all before I could get there. Do we have to get our torches and pitchforks ready?

Comment: Cheers for increasing my vocabulary, seems it's spelled baleeted though neither escapes Opera's spell-checker (which btw I never realized the niceness of through writing on SO ;-)

Comment: Sounds a bit pornographic :)

Comment: Pitchforks! Getcher pitchforks here! Ψ Ψ Ψ Ψ Ψ Ψ **available while supplies last; torches sold separately*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you suspect sock puppet accounts, either flag a post and give proper explanation, or send an email to team@stackoverflow.com or your friendly local neighborhood moderator. Then the proper steps can be taken (such as Atwood nuking accounts).

Comment: @TheTXI: "sock puppet", that's a term I hadn't heard before. I found this ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet) ), googe-first-hit too. Life is Good, so much to learn!

Answer (score 3):

Good eye!

Just flag the posts for moderator attention and it will be dealt with.

Comment: Flagged it for being a dupe, but only after Dr Dork appeared did the multiple account thing pop into mind. Alas, one flag per question.