# How should we deal with a duplicate user?

Tags: discussion, users, duplicate-user

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What’s the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)
>   [When is it right to report multiple accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26735/when-is-it-right-to-report-multiple-accounts)

I noticed today a user with a duplicate account.

Same name, location, age and photo.

This is **not** a sockpuppet account due to no upvotes.

I was wondering how the community should deal with this. Should we just email the SO team? Do we post it here on meta tagged [duplicate-user] or something?

My example is:

- [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5120/tony-benbrahim)
- [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80075/tony-benbrahim)

Comment: How should we deal with duplicate questions :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/suspended-user-creating-new-accounts
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13281/sockpuppets-who-expose-themselves
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26735/when-is-it-right-to-report-multiple-accounts http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21844/how-to-deal-with-people-creating-two-or-more-accounts-to-game-reputation

Comment: my apologies, I did do some searches and didn't notice these

Answer (score 3):

I would email the moderators. I found their email! team@stackoverflow.com